# Selenium, how do you instinatiate Opera webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, opera

For firefox,chrome,safarim,edge it works smth like this:

```
driver_instance = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But I can't find information on how to do the same for the Opera web driver and apparently it's supported. I downloaded the Opera webdriver, put it in my PATH but what command I'm supposed to run to make it run in Opera?

Comment: `Firefox` needs `webdriver.Firefox()`  instead of `webdriver.Chrome()` - and maybe the same is with `Opera` - maybe it needs `webdriver.Opera()`

Comment: I asked Google: `webdriver opera` and it gives me link to repo [OperaChromiumDriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver) and there is folder `examples` with file [desktop.py](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/blob/master/examples/desktop.py)

Comment: @furas Ok there's an example that use the webdrive.Remote but how do you run the Opera locally? Also is it not possible to run it without enabling this serivce first? I wonder why they didn't just make webdriver.Opera() method.

Answer (score 2):

Download opera driver here: https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

And use like this:

```
options.binary_location = r'location_of_opera.exe'
self.driver = webdriver.Opera(options=options, executable_path=r'location_of_operadriver.exe')
```

Example:[Example](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/automated-browser-testing-with-opera-and-selenium-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to initiate `opera` browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'location_of_opera.exe'
driver = webdriver.Opera(options=options, executable_path=r' location_of_operadriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: I get "module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Opera' when try to do it this way. How do you guys use the webdriver.Opera? For me there's no such attribute for webdriver and I can't see anything in the imports above that would allow this.